Resource recommendation for state of the art understanding of glass transition
Wikipedia identifies as an "Unsolved problem in physics" the question

What is the nature of the transition between a fluid or regular solid and a glassy phase?

citing a comment by Phil Anderson published in Science in 1995, which I reproduce below in full.

The deepest and most interesting unsolved problem in solid state theory is
probably the theory of the nature of glass and
the glass transition. This could be the next
breakthrough in the coming decade. The solution of the problem of spin glass in the
late 1970s had broad implications in unexpected fields like neural networks, computer algorithms, evolution, and computational complexity. The solution of the more
important and puzzling glass problem may
also have a substantial intellectual spin-off.
Whether it will help make better glass is
questionable.

Is there a recent (as of 2024) reference reviewing progress toward answering this question?

To be fair, since this was Phil’s area of expertise, of course this is the most interesting question…
